# How can I restore NuGet packages from a custom package source when using LINQPAD's lprun.exe?

Tags: c#, .net, linqpad

We use the [`lprun`](https://www.linqpad.net/lprun.aspx) feature of `LINQPAD` to run our build scripts; However as we are in a corporate environment we block access to the NuGet.org package source:

```
<add key="nuget.org" value="https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/" />
```

And instead use a corporate proxy e.g. a custom package source:

```
<add key="MyProxy" value="https://proxy.server/custom-nuget-repo" />
```

When developing locally these sources are specified in:

> C:\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming\Nuget.config

However `LINQPAD` is ignoring this file, how can I provide custom package sources when using the `lprun` to restore NuGet packages referenced?

Comment: lprun and LINQPad both use the file `%AppData%\LINQPad\NuGetSources.xml` for NuGet Package sources.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

lprun and LINQPad both use the file `%AppData%\LINQPad\NuGetSources.xml` for NuGet Package sources, so this is the file you need to edit.

In case this file doesn't exist, here is an example:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<NuGetSources>
  <Source Name="(default)" />
  <Source Name="My Packages" URI="https://www.myget.org/F/your-username-here/" UserName="Example" Password="base64encodedstring" Enabled="false" />
</NuGetSources>
```

Comment: That's great - what is the schema of this file? I need to create it, since it doesn't exist yet.

Comment: @SeanWorle I just updated my answer with some example content, I hope it helps

Answer (score 3):

From newer LinqPad versions this is built in to the LinqPad NuGet manager. Go to QueryProperties (F4) -> 'Add Nuget' -> 'Settings' and new package sources can be added just as easily as in VS.

Adding a new answer here since Google led me to this question first when trying to find the answer.

Comment: add nuget - is a paid option.